# IIS URL Rewrite (redirect)

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to replace "index" with "home" in my URL, e.g.:

`www.mywebsite.com/index` should redirect to `www.mywebsite.com/home`.

`www.mywebsite.com/index/contact` to `www.mywebsite.com/home/contact` and so on.

I tried applying this rule

```
<rule name="Replace index" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)(/index)(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="localhost:6782/home{R:3}" />
</rule>
```

The rule should pick up `(any-string)(/index)(any-other-string)` and replace it with `localhost:6782/home{any-other-string}` but it doesn't do anything.

[image: IIS regex test pattern]

Comment: The URL passed to match your `url` in `match` tag would be `index` or `index/contact`, so ask yourself whether you have given a valid regular expression.

Comment: That's correct, as well as  "something.com/index/something-else". So why it doesn't work?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 In your case, the mistake is simply the regular expression you chose `(.*)(/index)(.*)`. The `/` before `index` prevents it from matching any requests IIS passes, like I commented above. The way you tested out the regular expression won't help either, as your input does not match how IIS behaves. Very common mistake though, it is strange that Microsoft never tries to improve IIS Manager to prevent such.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to my question:

```
 <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to home" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="^index(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="home{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
 </rules>
```

**Tip**: be sure to clear the cache of the browser when trying out different rules (or use incognito mode)